# IgniteDataStreamer can't wirte data to ignite cluster

Tags: ignite

My ignite cluster is deploy on 2 machines. Each machine has 4 ignite process. like:

```
$jps
30678 CommandLineStartup
30723 CommandLineStartup
52461 Jps
30698 CommandLineStartup
30681 CommandLineStartup
```

When there is little data in the ignite cluster, I can use IgniteDataStreamer to write data into the ignite cluster. But if there have been more than 200G data in the ignite cluster, I can't use IgniteDataStreamer to write more data into the cluster. The memory and disk space are both enough. and the CPU load average is 2.09. The client log is :

```
[17:04:00,407][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Daemon mode: off
[17:04:00,407][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] OS: Linux
[17:04:00,407][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] OS user: mqq
[17:04:00,408][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.7
[17:04:00,408][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_72-b14 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.72-b04
[17:04:00,409][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] VM total memory: 2.9GB
[17:04:00,409][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Remote Management [restart: off, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
[17:04:00,409][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] IGNITE_HOME=/data1/home/igni1.5
[17:04:00,410][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] VM arguments: [-Xms3g, -Xmx3g, -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit, -XX:+AggressiveOpts, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+UseTLAB, -DIGNITE_QUIET=false]
[17:04:00,418][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Configured caches ['ignite-marshaller-sys-cache', 'ignite-sys-cache', 'ignite-atomics-sys-cache', 'cache_recmd']
[17:04:00,422][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] 3-rd party licenses can be found at: /data1/home/igni1.5/libs/licenses
[17:04:00,518][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Non-loopback local IPs: 10.0.0.1
[17:04:00,519][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Enabled local MACs: 9017ACC1492D
[17:04:00,530][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] Configured plugins:
[17:04:00,530][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor]   ^-- None
[17:04:00,530][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] 
[17:04:00,574][WARNING][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failure detection timeout will be ignored (one of SPI parameters has been set explicitly)
[17:04:00,627][INFO][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] IPC shared memory server endpoint started [port=48104, tokDir=/data1/home/igni1.5/work/ipc/shmem/e052dc07-8992-4834-87fd-abf84c0f644a-14472]
[17:04:00,628][INFO][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound shared memory communication to TCP port [port=48104, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]
[17:04:00,652][INFO][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47106, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]
[17:04:00,685][WARNING][main][NoopCheckpointSpi] Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
[17:04:00,749][WARNING][main][GridCollisionManager] Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
[17:04:00,755][WARNING][main][NoopSwapSpaceSpi] Swap space is disabled. To enable use FileSwapSpaceSpi.
[17:04:00,757][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[17:04:00,861][WARNING][main][GridCacheProcessor] Deployment mode for cache is not CONTINUOUS or SHARED (it is recommended that you change deployment mode and restart): ISOLATED
[17:04:01,040][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11217]
[17:04:01,138][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Exception on joining: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1241)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.sendJoinRequest(ClientImpl.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.joinTopology(ClientImpl.java:505)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.access$900(ClientImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.tryJoin(ClientImpl.java:1508)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1327)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:04:01,139][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Exception on joining: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1241)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.sendJoinRequest(ClientImpl.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.joinTopology(ClientImpl.java:505)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.access$900(ClientImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.tryJoin(ClientImpl.java:1508)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1327)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:04:01,140][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Exception on joining: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1241)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.sendJoinRequest(ClientImpl.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.joinTopology(ClientImpl.java:505)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.access$900(ClientImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.tryJoin(ClientImpl.java:1508)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1327)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:04:01,141][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Exception on joining: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1241)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.sendJoinRequest(ClientImpl.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.joinTopology(ClientImpl.java:505)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.access$900(ClientImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.tryJoin(ClientImpl.java:1508)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1327)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:05:01,179][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1505)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:917)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1547)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1003)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:929)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:815)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:584)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:554)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.actPutBatchs(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:30)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.main(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:12)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Join process timed out, did not receive response for join request (consider increasing 'joinTimeout' configuration property) [joinTimeout=60000, sock=Socket[addr=/10.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=35836]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1334)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:05:01,180][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1510)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:917)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1547)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1003)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:929)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:815)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:584)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:554)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.actPutBatchs(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:30)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.main(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:12)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1505)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Join process timed out, did not receive response for join request (consider increasing 'joinTimeout' configuration property) [joinTimeout=60000, sock=Socket[addr=/10.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=35836]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1334)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:05:01,193][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
[17:05:01,201][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-0-#58%grid_recmd%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Local node is not started or fully initialized [isStopping=true]
[17:05:01,201][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-1-#59%grid_recmd%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Local node is not started or fully initialized [isStopping=true]
[17:05:01,843][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-sock-reader-#3%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to read message [sock=Socket[addr=/10.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=35836], locNodeId=e052dc07-8992-4834-87fd-abf84c0f644a, rmtNodeId=198bc1a5-1b1d-4b65-bccb-b2eb5ad1ec9b]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3415ddf5
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:105)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$SocketReader.body(ClientImpl.java:888)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:245)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readMap(IgniteUtils.java:4890)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.TcpDiscoveryNode.readExternal(TcpDiscoveryNode.java:559)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:3302)
    at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(TreeMap.java:3234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:102)
    ... 2 more
[17:05:01,845][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-sock-reader-#3%grid_recmd%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Connection failed [sock=Socket[addr=/10.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=35836], locNodeId=e052dc07-8992-4834-87fd-abf84c0f644a]
java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:245)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readMap(IgniteUtils.java:4890)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.TcpDiscoveryNode.readExternal(TcpDiscoveryNode.java:559)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:3302)
    at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(TreeMap.java:3234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$SocketReader.body(ClientImpl.java:888)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
[17:05:01,876][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%grid_recmd] 

>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 1.5.0-final#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2f3f62231f42a59951bf34c39577c1bec stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid name: grid_recmd
>>> Grid uptime: 00:01:02:580


class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:882)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.actPutBatchs(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:30)
    at IgniteOnlineWriteTest.main(IgniteOnlineWriteTest.java:12)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1510)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:917)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1547)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1003)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:929)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:815)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:584)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:554)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1505)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Join process timed out, did not receive response for join request (consider increasing 'joinTimeout' configuration property) [joinTimeout=60000, sock=Socket[addr=/10.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=35836]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1334)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

the ignite process's JVM_OPTS is :

```
export JVM_OPTS="-Xms5g -Xmx5g -Xmn2g -server -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -XX:+UseP
arNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB"
```

the srv.xml is

```
   <bean id="cacheA" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <property name="name" value="cache_recmd"/>
        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/><!-- partition -->
        <property name="affinity">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                <property name="hashIdResolver" >
                  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.AffinityNodeAddressHashResolver"/>
                </property>
                <property name="partitions" value="280" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="backups" value="0"/>
        <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
        <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
        <property name="atomicWriteOrderMode" value="PRIMARY"/>
        <property name="memoryMode" value="ONHEAP_TIERED"/><!-- memory tire -->
        <property name="startSize" value="#{30 * 1024 * 1024}"/> 
        <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="#{512 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
        <property name="swapEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="evictionPolicy">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                <property name="maxMemorySize" value="#{1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="rebalanceMode" value="ASYNC"/>
        <property name="rebalanceBatchSize" value="#{1024 * 1024}"/>
        <property name="rebalanceThrottle" value="100"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="igniA" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration" scope="singleton">
        <property name="gridName" value="grid_recmd"/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
        <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="0"/><!-- 0 means disable metrics log -->
        <property name="deploymentMode" value="ISOLATED"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="47500"/>
                <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/>
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                      <property name="shared" value="true"/>
                      <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>10.0.0.1:47500..47520</value>
                            <value>10.0.0.2:47500..47520</value>
                        </list>
                      </property>                      
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="joinTimeout" value="60000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="socketWriteTimeout" value="30000"/>
                <property name="connectTimeout" value="50000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="swapSpaceSpi">
             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.swapspace.file.FileSwapSpaceSpi">
                 <property name="baseDirectory" value="/data1/home/igni1.5/my/swp"/>
             </bean>
         </property>
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
          <list>
            <ref bean="cacheA"/>
          </list>
        </property>
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: According to the log the client can't start, so it looks like the issue is at the very beginning? How can it depend on the data size then? Are you sure that you're properly using the `IgniteDataStreamer`? Also what is happening on the server nodes? Are they starting and discovering each other?

Comment: `try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cliXML);IgniteDataStreamer<String, Object[]> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer("cache_recmd")) {   
    stmr.allowOverwrite(true);    
    Object[] v = ...                         
    stmr.addData(key, v);
}`

Comment: My IgniteDataStreamer program can run normally when there is little data in the ignite cluster. but when the data becomes larger in the ignite cluster, eg:200G data. My IgniteDataStream program can't run . The  server nodes is normal, they can starting and discovering each other.

Comment: At which point it fails? In the log you provided the client failed to even connect, so it couldn't even start loading data. I doubt that the data size could influence that. Was the client restarted? Can you attach full log files from all nodes?